# Need help getting switchable graphics working under Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ati, radeon, vaio, catalyst, switchable-graphics

According to "Details" (System Settings-->Details), my Sony VAIO VPC-CB15F is using *only* my integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 graphics card (it says the graphics are "Intel Sandybridge Mobile"), however the "Additional Drivers" screen (System Settings-->Software & Updates-->Additional Drivers) seems to imply that I am using my AMD Radeon HD 6630M...

Yes, I have that stupid switchable graphics setup (**never** again, it's NVIDIA or *nothing* next time!).

Anyway, the "Additional Drivers" screen (System Settings-->Software & Updates-->Additional Drivers) says that I using "X.Org X Server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source, tested)", however I see no way to change between the two graphics cards, use *only* my Radeon HD 6630M (which would be *preferable* anyway, *if* it works without issue) or identify *which* graphics card I am currently using...

If anyone can give me help getting my Radeon HD 6630M working *exclusively* or getting the switchable crap setup again (I just did a "clean" install of Ubuntu 14.10), I'd be most appreciative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better install the proprietary drivers from the release repository :

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-pxpress
sudo ln -svT /usr/lib /usr/lib64 #Only for Ubuntu 64bits
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

> never again, it's NVIDIA or nothing next time!

My previous laptop was nvidia hybrid and it was as difficult as for amd graphic cards to configure :)

Comment: I did that and although it installed Catalyst, running it (Catalyst) says:
"There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.
It could be caused by the following.

No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig."

Comment: Did you reboot ? During install, it told me that no compatible graphics where found, and after reboot, it was ok.

Comment: Give me a sec... I'll try.

Comment: Oh, I forgot one thing : if you are on 64 bits system, execute the following : sudo ln -svT /usr/lib /usr/lib64; I'll edit my post too.

Comment: Do I really need to? I just restarted my computer and not only is Catalyst working, but much to my surprise Ubuntu is apparently using it by default (now?)! Seemingly it's all working fine, so will my failure to run sudo ln -svT /usr/lib /usr/lib64; really matter?

Comment: If all is ok congrats, and do not do anything else ;) yes, amd graphics is now used by default. execute 'sudo amdccle' to configure it. i don't remember exactely what, but something needed to access fglrx through lib64 directory, so if you see that in the future as an error message, you will know what to do : just create the link to fix it.