# Can't access System Settings or Catalyst!

Tags: system-settings, catalyst

Recently I did a "clean" install of Ubuntu 14.10 and I had everything running fine, using my AMD Radeon HD 6630M as the default graphics card, without issue (I have one of those *stupid* dual-graphics cards setups).

But when I was having problems with the HDMI output (the screen flickering and the entire desktop off-center), I thought it might be a driver issue, so I changed my video card to the Intel card using Catalyst... Then everything went pear-shaped.

Now, I cannot access System Settings at all - it just changes the mouse/touchpad cursor to the "loading" variant, then nothing.

Further to this, when my laptop automatically suspends after the user-specified time (which I cannot see, because I cannot access the System Settings), I cannot come out of standby mode... Pressing keys on my laptop (well, the external keyboard - my laptop's keyboard no longer works) does nothing but causes my laptop to continue to display a black screen!
I tried to change back to my Radeon HD 6630M using Catalyst, but after entering the correct password in the pop-up dialog box, I get nothing!

Then I tried to re-install it as per my original support request:
[Need help getting switchable graphics working under Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546800/need-help-getting-switchable-graphics-working-under-ubuntu-14-10)

But all I get is errors:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-pxpress
[sudo] password for gregoryopera: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fglrx-pxpress is already the newest version.
fglrx is already the newest version.
fglrx-amdcccle is already the newest version.
fglrx-core is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
gregoryopera@gregoryopera-VPCCB15FG:~$ sudo ln -svT /usr/lib /usr/lib64 #Only for Ubuntu 64bits
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/lib64’: File exists
gregoryopera@gregoryopera-VPCCB15FG:~$ sudo amdconfig --initial
amdconfig: No supported adapters detected*
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, everything's fixed.

What I had to do was purge (i.e. *completely* remove) all of my AMD Radeon HD 6630M drivers and software:

```
sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"
```

Restart.

Install all of my AMD Radeon HD 6630M drivers and software from scratch again:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-pxpress
sudo ln -svT /usr/lib /usr/lib64 #Only for Ubuntu 64bits
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

Restart.

Everything works fine now!

*Note to self, avoid the HDMI port and the embedded (Intel) graphics...*

Thanks go to @BrunoPereira and @Snorky35 for their respective instructions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/68312/230107) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/546816/230107)